# What is the time complexity of retrieving an element from LinkedHashMap in case of collision?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Suppose that I have a LinkedHashMap object with only 8 buckets numbered from 0 to 7.
Now I want to add elements. I added 7 elements and the result is as follows:

1) Element_1: Bucket number 2. This becomes the starting of the linked list which LinkedHashMap maintains to maintain the insertion order.
1) Element_2: Bucket number 3. This is linked to Element_1
2) Element_3: Bucket Number 1. This is linked to Element_2
3) Element_4: Bucket Number 4. This is linked to Elemetn_3
4) Element_5: Bucket Number 5. This is linked to Element_4
5) Element_6: Bucket Number 3. This is linked to Element_5 (Collision has occurred)
6) Element_7: Bucket Number 3. This is linked to Element_6(Again a collision)

Now suppose I want to retrieve Element_7. The hashing of this element gives me ***bucket number 3***. Now the elements in ***bucket number 3*** are **Element_2**, **Element_6**, **Element_7**.
So what is the order of traversal of the following two:
a) Element_2-> Element_3->Element_4->Element_5->Element_6->Element_7.
**OR**
b) Element_2->Element_6->Element_7.

I thought that the answer would be (a) because LinkedHashMap maintains a linked list to maintain the insertion order. So if the order is (b) it means a particular element is storing two references, one for the next element in order of insertion, and one for the next element in the same bucket.

If the answer is (b), how does the particular element decides, which one to visit,i.e. out of the two references, which one to pick.

The use case scenario is hypothetical, and it may not be in correlation with the fact that with number of elements less than number of buckets, the chances of collision is less.
Please answer keeping in mind the above scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the insertion order linked list is totally irrelevant to the cost of looking up an item by key? In other words, the cost of lookup should be the same as that of `HashMap`.

Comment: It would very weird (and pretty pointless) if the result was a). It would just be a linked list!

Comment: If you had 7 elements you would have 16 buckets normally. But the example still valid.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedHashMap extends HashMap and hence linking is irrelevant for `get`, so on adding linkage they should not have made LinkedHashMap less efficient on `get` - as get does not need that linkage.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but I can't say that I find the chain of reasoning entirely convincing.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have noticed this implementation. But as I said, in a regular HashMap a particular entry (Map.Entry object) stores the reference of next Map.Entry object (within the same bucket) But in case of LinkedHashMap the reference will be of the element which was inserted next. So to iterate over the elements in the same bucket, does a particular element stores two references, one for the next inserted element and one for the next element in the same bucket? If yes, how does it decide, which reference to select?

Comment: LinkedHashMap only provides _additional_ links; the bucket links will still exist, out of necessity, out of class inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap extends HashMap and its `get` method calls HashMap's `getEntry` method. HashMap's implementation stores each bucket in a separate array, so it would not need to loop over the whole dataset, only on the data within that bucket. Taken form Oracle JDK 7:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**

`e.next` is defined in `HashMap.Entry` and is within the same bucket, as opposed to `e.after` and `e.before` defined in `LinkedHasMap.Entry` which can be in different buckets.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have notices this implementation. But as I said, in a regular HashMap a particular entry (Map.Entry object) stores the reference of next Map.Entry object (within the same bucket)
But in case of LinkedHashMap the reference will be of the element which was inserted next. So to iterate over the elements in the same bucket, does a particular element stores two references, one for the next inserted element and one for the next element in the same bucket?
If yes, how does it decide, which reference to select?

Comment: See my edit: `LinkedHashMap.Entry` extends `HashMap.Entry` and adds a `before` and an `after` fields which are the next and previous nodes in the map (and could be in a different bucket), but when calling `get`, it is the `next` field from `Map.Entry` that is used, which is within the same bucket.

Comment: Hi Assylias, I think you are definitely right because then only a Map makes sense. But just for cross-clarification, so there are two references: the field "after" stores the insertion order reference and "next" stores the reference to the next element in the same bucket. 
I am sorry for asking again and again, but I am just completely bogged down with the confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was indeed a great help.